# eclipse automatic file encoding detection

Tags: eclipse, encoding

Is there a way to make eclipse to autodetect the file type?

I've tried going to

```
Eclipse-prefferences->general->content-types->default-encoding
```

And putting there the file-type, for instance utf-8, but then it show all the files of the project with this encoding while some other files had a different encoding so some characters are badly encoded on these files.

Then I know I can change one files encoding

```
right-click on a file->preferences->resources
```

But I would like a way to let eclipse do it automatically instead of going one by one for all those bad encoded files.

They are mostly php files.

Comment: What sort of file? For text files it generally isn't possible to work out the encoding for certain.

Comment: no no, the're php files. Edited thanks

Answer (score 0):

Autodetect Encoding Plugin
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/autodetect-encoding

> 'Autodetect: Set Automatically'
>   This only applies if the file properties encoding is not specified.